# Differentiate a *function* in maxima

Tags: maxima

Given a function:

```
f(r, phi) := [r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi)];
```

I can find the derivative w.r.t. the first argument by providing arguments that turn it into an expression, like this:

```
f1(a, b) := diff(f(a, b), a);
```

But that's kind of wordy and round about.  Is there a way to directly say "derivative of `f` w.r.t first argument?"

Comment: Hi Martin, it's not clear what you want to accomplish. If you enter `diff(f(a, b), a)` then you'll get the derivative wrt the first argument -- maybe you can explain in what sense that is not what you need. PS. Bear in mind that the function body is not evaluated until the function is called. For that reason, `f1(1, 1)` will cause an error because it will try to evaluate `diff(f(1, 1), 1)`. Try `f1(a, b) := ''(diff(f(a, b), a)` instead (that's two single quotes, not a double quote). Or try `define(f(a, b), diff(f(a, b), a))` instead.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I think you've answered my question, namely that functions aren't really first class objects, separate from expressions, in Maxima.  I'm looking for a `fundiff`, so that I can write e.g.`fundiff(f, 1)` to get the partial, or maybe `fundiff(f)` to get the 2x2 matrix derivative.

Comment: And thanks for the tip about quote-quote.  I see that without it, the RHS is unevaluated until the parameters are substituted, which as you point out is not what I want.